# Visual Studio 2013 Designer Support for Windows Embedded Compact 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

This is a cross-post from [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/909ff266-00f6-4ee5-b918-9c79db7250bc/wec2013-vs-2013-cf-39-designer-support-xmta-asmmetadll-etc?forum=winembmngdapp).  There was no answer there, so I'm trying here.

In Visual Studio 2008, we were able to generate Visual Studio designer support for Windows CE projects by adding .xmta files to our project.  The Visual Studio 2008 build system would then automatically generate a .asmmeta.dll file for the project.  This file was just meta-information used by the designer.  For example, it would contain the [Designer("...")] attributes and such that would allow control developers to add designer support for their custom controls.

This doesn't seem to be possible with Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Embedded Compact 2013 (WEC2013).  However, these .asmmeta.dll files are present in the WEC2013 SDK for the WEC2013 standard controls, so someone, somewhere knows how to generate them.

Does anyone here know how to generate .asmmeta.dll files in Visual Studio 2013 for the WEC2013 platform?